# Copy cut out of an image to a new image using Numpy or OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Is it possible to copy only a specific region from an image and paste it to another image using either OpenCV or Numpy in python?

Lets say I have a RGB image and a grayscale mask of an image. (both are the same size)

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to copy the boat only where the pixels of the mask overlap to a specific part of a new image?

[image]

Here is the code I tried.

```
image1 = cv2.imread("boat.png")
mask = cv2.imread("boat_mask.png")
image2 = cv2.imread("sea.png")
width, height = image1.shape
image2[y:y+height,x:x+width] = image1[mask==255]
```

This doesn't work because **image1[mask==255]** no longer has a 2d shape.

Solution:

```
image2_cutout = image2[y:y+height,x:x+width]
image2_cutout[mask==255] = image1[mask==255]
image2[y:y+height,x:x+width] = image2_cutout
```

Comment: That's true, `image1[mask==255]` produces a flat array, but as far as it has the same number of cells as the view it is copied to it should work. But it would just write the cells to the view in C-order. I'd suggest you first get a view and then index it with mask like `image2_view[mask==255] = image1[mask255]`. This will synchronise positions

Comment: Good thinking! It works if i synchronize the positions. Thank you!

Comment: if you're interested in transparency, rather than simple masks: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```py
import cv2


image1 = cv2.imread("data/boat.png")
_, mask = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("data/masked_boat.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image2 = cv2.imread("data/sea.jpg")
width, height, _ = image1.shape
y = 300
x = 300

masked_normalized = cv2.bitwise_and(image1, image1, mask=mask)

cut_from_bg = image2[x:x+width, y:y+height]
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(cut_from_bg, cut_from_bg, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask))

dst = cv2.add(img1_bg, masked_normalized)

image2[x:width + x, y:height + y] = dst
cv2.imshow("sea_with_boat", image2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The first thing that I do here is that I take a `mask` of boat and using `cv2.bitwise_and` I get a real masked image of boat. Then I cut a part of sea where I want to place the boat and cut out here the boat shape. Then I combine masked boat image and cutted sea image using `cv2.add` and after that I just put this part of image on the original image of sea.